# Error while adding custom header param in Volley

Tags: java, android, http-headers, android-volley

My code is like this...

```
@Override
 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("Cookie: sessionid=","07yy02a83089836ddabd4f6bf57e9677");
  return params;
}
```

when i print it on my server side with $_COOKIE['sessionid'] it is coming like...

```
  ": 07yy02a83089836ddabd4f6bf57e9677"
```

a :(colon) is being added to the value of that param. i couldn't find the reason after long search in internet helps! hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by setting like this...

```
 params.put("Cookie","sessionid=07yy02a83089836ddabd4f6bf57e9677");
```